# Laravel 6.0 local server

Tags: laravel, hardware

I have this project in laravel 6.0 stored locally in my laptop. I am just wondering if I can still run this same project to another local PC and use it as a server for local only. I know it would be better to have a dedicated server for this project but this is not a bigtime system. I just want to run it only in my  property. Is it okay if the said server is with these specs?

Processor- Intel® Core™ i7-4770

MotherBoard- Gigabyte GA-Z97X Gaming 7 ATX

Cooler- Stock Cooler

RAM- 1x8gb ddr3 Team Elite

GPU- Asus RX 570 4gb ddr5

HDD- WD Green 1TB (100% Healthy)

PSU- Seasonic M12II 620watts fully modular

I don't know if I should I this here or to another site. Thanks if you could help me enlightened.

Comment: yes you can.but you have to do same configuration in the other computer as well(the computer you are trying to host the project).

Comment: If that works out depends on your application and what it does. Generally speaking, you can run a Laravel application on a RaspberryPi and similar spec'd hardware with ease. Not so much if your app performs video transcoding for example.

Comment: you can sir use ngrock to tunnel your url

Comment: Hey MDB! Perhaps give the [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange a visit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in addition to the hardware of the machine where you want to host the application, a more thorough study would be necessary such as the **type of application** you want to host and the **data traffic** that you will have. In addition to the **type of database manager** you are going to use, if it will be hosted on the same machine or remotely.

As you said, I understand that it is for domestic use and I imagine that you will use MySql hosted on the same machine (correct me if I am wrong), so with the hardware you described it should not cause you problems.

Hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware should suffice, however if you can manage it, try setting it up on a Linux command only OS. Most importantly—if possible—replace your HDD with an SSD, even if it is a small one, it will improve a lot the performance of your application.